# INT vs CALL on Asm instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

i searched over web but i could not found any difference between int and call on asm.
Whats the difference between call and int asm instructions?

They both call some functions 
"int" calls system functions
"call" calls user functions.

But in real mode they same?
I can't understand the difference much.

And , does int calls ivt ( interrupt vector table ) that has defined on bios ?
But call can do same operation also ? why needed call or divided both ?

Comment: BIOS interrupt calls can be made by just knowing the interrupt/function number - the actual address you don't need to know. It's an abstraction, just like function names.

Comment: its in the instruction set documentation which is all over the web in countless forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Superficially, the difference is:

CALL takes the procedure address, which can be either near or far, and provided either as a constant or in a register. Meanwhile, INT takes an interrupt number, which is used as an index in the interrupt vector table at 0000:0000 (in real mode) to look up the address. CALL pushes the return address (either near or far) to the stack; INT pushes the flags register and the return address (always far).

In protected mode, INT is rather different. It involves a user to kernel mode switch.

INT is used to consume services of BIOS and DOS. CALL is for invoking your own procedures. You can make an interrupt vector point at one of your procedures, but what would be the point?

Some real mode DOS programs that have services intended for consumption by other programs also used to hook interrupt vectors. For example, the  Microsoft mouse driver (a regular program, not a part of DOS proper) would hook the INT 33h vector, and programs would use that to interact with the mouse. For the vector to remain valid, those programs would have to stay resident in memory.

Comment: For further reading would you recommend also other sources then those mentioned in my answer? Something similar to Vlad Pirogov's "The Assembly Programming Master Book"? Where did **you** learn the answer?

Comment: It's been a while, I don't remember. Jourdain's book, probably.

Comment: `int` is not *that* different in protected mode.  It still transfers control to an interrupt handler according to a table maintained by the kernel.  And it still pushes EFLAGS and CS:EIP (onto the kernel stack, but that's a minor difference).  It's still mostly used for calling functions in the kernel, e.g. from 32-bit Linux or *BSD user-space with `int 0x80`, by putting args and a system-call code in registers exactly like the ABI for DOS/BIOS `int` calls.

Comment: In protected mode a "call gate" segment may be specified as destination address of a `call` instruction. In this case a context switch to the kernel also happens. Some older x86 SunOS versions used this variant to enter system calls instead of an `int` instruction...

Answer (score 1):

> i searched over web but i could not found any difference between int and call on asm. Whats the difference between call and int asm instructions?

Comprehensive answer would be very long and short simplifying opinion based answer would be insufficient. So I'll answer only the

> i searched over web but i could not found any..

In your web searches prefer credible and professional information sources and you'll find what you are after.

I'd recommend starting at [Wikipedia: INT (x86 instruction)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)), read also linked and "see also" articles (certainly [Wikipedia: Interrupt descriptor table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) and [Wikipedia: System call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), other key terms probably are `call gate` and `interrupt gate`...) and get acquainted with external references.

Among the most important references is the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) where **CHAPTER 6 → PROCEDURE CALLS, INTERRUPTS, AND EXCEPTIONS** should answer all you wanted to know

Comment: Typically, you don't have the privilege to access the memory where the interrupt code is. You can just cause the interrupt, which changes the privilege-level (including memory mapping from user space to system space).